# Change character set on Microsoft R Server 9.0.1

Tags: character-encoding, server, microsoft-r

**Q:** How to you change/update the character set on Microsoft R Server?

**Issue:** I am trying to read a CSV that is delimited with '§' but the R Server is not able to interperet the '§' character when I work remotely. Similarly for other characters like 'ø' , 'æ' and 'å'. When I work locally it's not an issue.

For example:

This works fine:

```
> x <- '§'
> x
[1] "§"
```

But when i login remotely to the server the following happens:

```
REMOTE> x <- '§'
REMOTE> x
[1] "?"
```

**Setup:** I am running Microsoft R Server 9.0.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Detailed sessionInfo:

> REMOTE> sessionInfo() R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Platform:
>   x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows Server >= 2012
>   x64 (build 9200)
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Norwegian (Bokm�l)_Norway.1252  [2]
>   LC_CTYPE=Norwegian (Bokm�l)_Norway.1252    [3] LC_MONETARY=Norwegian
>   (Bokm�l)_Norway.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=Norwegian (Bokm�l)_Norway.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0 RevoUtils_10.0.2
>   RevoMods_10.0.0      [4] RevoScaleR_9.0.1     lattice_0.20-34
>   rpart_4.1-10
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] R6_2.2.0
>   tools_3.3.2            CompatibilityAPI_1.1.0 [4] codetools_0.2-15
>   grid_3.3.2             iterators_1.0.8        [7] foreach_1.4.3
>   mrupdate_1.0.0         jsonlite_1.1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to installing version 9.1 of Microsoft R Server I also had to make the following change for the server to work correctly with remote login:

Stop the service 'RServe9.0.0.0'
and go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Server\R_SERVER\o16n\RServe\RScripts\source.R on the compute nodes
and change

````
```
#add more here if necessary......
```
````

to

````
```
#add more here if necessary......
options(encoding = "UTF-8") 
```
````

and then start that service again, you should be able to use §.

Thanks to Microsoft for providing this fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, and has been patched in Microsoft R Server 9.1, please upgrade to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yeah i had got in touch with Microsoft and they provided me with the newest version, although I had to make a slight tweak to the source code to make it work. See the answer below.